# htaccess permanent redirect from file that doesn't exists anymore

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo, prestashop, permanent

I got an old Peel shop that I moved on Prestashop. Before switch it live, I would like to keep the Google ranks I got on some products (approximatly 100 products).

So far I make my tests on Prestashop pre-prod server, with a domain name like "mywebsite.com/~subfolder/" (forced by hosting company). All products have been imported from Peel to Prestashop.

I thought that a simple

```
Options +FollowSymlinks    
RewriteEngine on 
RedirectPermanent /~subfolder/achat/product_detail.php?id=300 http://www.mywebsite.com/~subfolder/my/new/url-300.html
```

would worked, but I'm always redirected to the Prestashop not found page. As far as I see, it doesn't accept the fact that "achat/product_detail.php" does not exist.

I also tried

```
RewriteRule ^/~subfolder/achat/produit_details.php?id=110$ /~subfolder/layette-en-laine-et-soie/110-brassiere-laine-et-soie.html [L,R=301]
```

which is not working better.

What is the correct way to handle this? If possible in a relative way meaning that I would prefer not to have to modify the file when I will switch Prestashop live (and change http://mywebsite.com/~subfolder to http://www.mywebsite.com).

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Thanks,

Nicolas

PS : if needed, below my htaccess file generated by prestashop (I removed the tests mentionned above) :

```
# .htaccess automaticaly generated by PrestaShop e-commerce open-source solution
# WARNING: PLEASE DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE MANUALLY. IF NECESSARY, ADD YOUR SPECIFIC CONFIGURATION WITH THE HTACCESS GENERATOR IN BACK OFFICE
# http://www.prestashop.com - http://www.prestashop.com/forums

SetEnv PHP_VER 5_TEST
SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0

AuthUserFile    /XXXX
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Veuillez vous identifier"
AuthType Basic


require valid-user

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# URL rewriting module activation
RewriteEngine on

# URL rewriting rules
RewriteRule ^api/?(.*)$ /~subfolder/webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)\-([a-z0-9]+)(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$ /~subfolder/img/p/$1-$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\-([0-9]+)/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$ /~subfolder/img/p/$1-$2.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$ /~subfolder/img/p/$1/$1$2.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$ /~subfolder/img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$ /~subfolder/img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$ /~subfolder/img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$ /~subfolder/img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$ /~subfolder/img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$ /~subfolder/img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$ /~subfolder/img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^c/([0-9]+)(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$ /~subfolder/img/c/$1$2.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^c/([a-zA-Z-]+)/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.jpg$ /~subfolder/img/c/$1.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$ /~subfolder/img/c/$1$2.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.html /~subfolder/product.php?id_product=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9-]*/([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.html /~subfolder/product.php?id_product=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*(/[a-zA-Z0-9-]*)+ /~subfolder/category.php?id_category=$1&noredirect=1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]* /~subfolder/category.php?id_category=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)__([a-zA-Z0-9-]*) /~subfolder/supplier.php?id_supplier=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)_([a-zA-Z0-9-]*) /~subfolder/manufacturer.php?id_manufacturer=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^content/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*) /~subfolder/cms.php?id_cms=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^content/category/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*) /~subfolder/cms.php?id_cms_category=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^page-non-trouvee$ /~subfolder/404.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^adresse$ /~subfolder/address.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^adresses$ /~subfolder/addresses.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^authentification$ /~subfolder/authentication.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^meilleures-ventes$ /~subfolder/best-sales.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^panier$ /~subfolder/cart.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^contactez-nous$ /~subfolder/contact-form.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^bons-de-reduction$ /~subfolder/discount.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^suivi-commande-invite$ /~subfolder/guest-tracking.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^historique-des-commandes$ /~subfolder/history.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^identite$ /~subfolder/identity.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fabricants$ /~subfolder/manufacturer.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^mon-compte$ /~subfolder/my-account.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^nouveaux-produits$ /~subfolder/new-products.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^commande$ /~subfolder/order.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^details-de-la-commande$ /~subfolder/order-follow.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^commande-rapide$ /~subfolder/order-opc.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^avoirs$ /~subfolder/order-slip.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^mot-de-passe-oublie$ /~subfolder/password.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^promotions$ /~subfolder/prices-drop.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^recherche$ /~subfolder/search.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^plan-du-site$ /~subfolder/sitemap.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^magasins$ /~subfolder/stores.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fournisseurs$ /~subfolder/supplier.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

# Catch 404 errors
ErrorDocument 404 /~subfolder/404.php

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

FileETag INode MTime Size
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot match against the query string using a `RewriteRule` and you cannot include query strings in the `Redirect` directives. You need to use a `RewriteCond` for the query string:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=110$ 
RewriteRule ^~subfolder/achat/produit_details.php$ /~subfolder/layette-en-laine-et-soie/110-brassiere-laine-et-soie.html [L,R=301]
```

Note that you also need to remove the leading **/** in the match because it gets stripped by the rewrite engine within the .htaccess file.

Comment: Hello,Many thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't work... Still got a not found page. Regarding to the enclosed htaccess file, it there a specific place I should put your lines? Do you have any idea why it doesn't work? Thanks !

Comment: @NicolasBONNIOT you need to put the rules before the existing `RewriteRule`s.

Answer (score 0):

I finally answer my question : in case detailled above, the solution to have a valid redirection is below :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=110$ 
RewriteRule ^achat/produit_details.php$ /~subfolder/layette-en-laine-et-soie/110-brassiere-laine-et-soie.html [L,R=301]
```

To be done for each product id that need a redirection
Hope it will help !